# “Half of hamburgers are eaten.”

Tags: grammatical-number

> “Half of hamburgers are eaten.”

If there are no restricting modifiers in front of “hamburgers,” does “hamburgers” mean all hamburgers?

For example, there are 100 hamburgers in reality. If I just say half of hamburgers are eaten, is only “50 hamburgers are eaten” correct? That is, under no contexts, does “hamburgers” mean all hamburgers? Can they be 40/80 hamburgers or 25/50 hamburgers, not 50/100 hamburgers?

To specify the number of things, is a determiner mandatory or optional?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The modifier half is what's transforming 100 into 50. What do you mean by "under no contexts"

Comment: The sentence makes no sense. If you were talking about a particular hundred hamburgers, you would say 'Half [of] the hamburgers have been eaten."

Comment: @Paribus Ceteris Is “all” implied before plural nouns unless there are no explicit determiners?

Comment: Yes, if there is no determiner, it sounds like you mean "half of all hamburgers in the world, ever".

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes, I know, but I wonder implication of “all” is compulsory.

Comment: @stangdon Yes, that’s what I mean, but is it compulsory?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "is the implication compulsory".  "all of them ever" is the implication.  That's what it means.  If you don't mean that, use a determiner.

Comment: @stangdon Is a determiner obligatory to specify the number of hamburgers?

Comment: The speaker must have a specific number in mind to be able to make a statement about 'half' of them. If you mean _all hamburgers [that exist]_ you need to say so.

Comment: What is the **real** problem, not the problem about hamburgers.  Either you are trying to understand something, or you are trying to communicate something.  I guess think you read, or the thing you want to say are not about hamburgers.  Please tell us what the actual context is.  Because when you give a context like "hamburgers" what you say is understood only in that context.  The answer might not apply to the real problem that you have.

Comment: The simple fact is that you wouldn't say "Half of hamburgers are eaten". You do need some kind of determiner for it to make sense: "the" or "all" or something.